# Cannot Install Package GISTools for Linux(Lubuntu)

Tags: r, install.packages

I am wanting to have the package `GISTools`. I typed in the command

```
install.packages('GISTools')
```

which it goes onto install 100%, in addition to the `rgeos` `dependency`. See below what `Rstudio` give me.

- installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...

  ```
  package ‘rgeos’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
  configure: CXX: g++
  configure: rgeos: 0.3-19
  checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
  configure: svn revision: 524
  checking for geos-config... no
  no
  configure: error: geos-config not found or not executable.

  ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
  ```
- removing `/home/sethie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgeos`

  ```
  Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘rgeos’ is not available for package ‘GISTools’
  ```
- removing `/home/sethie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/GISTools`

  ```
  Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘GISTools’ had non-zero exit status

  The downloaded source packages are in
      `/tmp/RtmpkDvA75/downloaded_packages`
  ```

Comment: "*The GEOS library is external to the package, and, when installing the package from source, must be correctly installed first.*" - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html - I suspect that might be your issue.

Comment: Thank you, when trying to install [rgeos] the same non-zero exit status appears. I'm starting to think that maybe [GISTools] is related [maptools], which means I may already have it?

Comment: Ok, the problem was I couldn't install [rgeos]. In order to install this package I had to install, on ubuntu, [libgeos-dev] by using the terminal "sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev".  After I installed this and [libgeos-3.5.0] just in case I was finally able to install [rgeos] in R. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because the GISTools dependency library should be installed before, that is, rgeos. this is solved in installing packages individually
first
download GISTools http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/src/contrib/GISTools_0.7-1.tar.gz
download rgeos form https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rgeos_0.5-9.tar.gz
first install GISTools dependency is rgeos,and next install GISTools